# Верстка на Bootstrap 4. Работа с col-lg-

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, bootstrap, bootstrap4

У меня такой вопрос, вот если я хочу задать ширину и высоту для шапки сайта на Bootstrap 4, то мне не нужно устанавливать `col-lg-` ?

Comment: Просто прописываете width, и все. А зачем вам длина? Шапка всегда должна быть по длине окна.

Comment: @VerNick, очень странное утверждение что "шапка должна быть по длинне окна", простите но кому должна и чегойта ради? во первых есть множество сайтов не с резиновой версткой, во вторых вполне возможно что у автора не резиновая(адаптивная) верстка на сайте и именно она ему и нужна.

Comment: @ВладимирКлыков Ну как бы почти на всех сайтах шапка по длине окна.Я еще не встречал сайтов с шапками не на длину окна. Хотя бы шапка того же Stack Overflow по его длине.

Comment: @VerNick, вам бы немного, лет на 10 в прошлое, тогда резиновых сайтов почти небыло =) не сочтите за рекламу, но вот то что пришло в голову сразу просто www.lostfilm.tv www.ebay.com там "шапки" не на весь экран =)

Comment: @ВладимирКлыков А, я понял, о чем вы) Ну у bootstrapa есть адаптивная верстка, и если вы навбару пропишете ширину, он от этого не перестанет быть адаптивным.

Comment: @VerNick я не силен в данном фреймворке, но думаю что вполне себе есть способы заставить его вести себя как статичная верстка =)

Comment: Ну например если вы запихнете его в `div` с классом `container`, то он станет длиной, например как длина блока с вопросами и ответами) Но если вы хотите определенной длины и ширину, тогда вас ждет col )))

Comment: Нет, мой сайт не адаптивный.

Comment: Просто, у меня есть макет, и у него есть шапка, и когда я устанавливаю col-lg-12, то он у меня находится по середине (то есть не во весь экран)...
А у меня шапка во весь экран, то есть 100%

Comment: И поэтому я спрашивал, могу ли я не использовать col-lg- для шапки если мне нужен header во весь экран?